# Spring on Glassfish - Get Hibernate parameters logged?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, logging, glassfish

I have a Spring application running on the Glassfish Webserver and I'm seeing some very strange behavior in hibernate queries.  I would like to be able to see the query AND its parameters, not just the '?' placeholder. How do I do this?

I have tried going in through the admin console, adding and configuring the following loggers to 'FINEST' in the server config

- javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging
- log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type

I'm still not getting the parameter binding.

How do I do this?

Comment: have you set "show_sql", "format_sql" to true in hibernate.cfg.xml ? Plus you need to set log4j as : `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` and likes.

Comment: @ringbearer there isn't a hibernate.cfg.xml - it seems like that configuration is being done via glassfish maybe? I really don't know how all these pieces fit together to be honest, I just know that update statements are getting logged but the values I'm expecting to see aren't appearing in the db. But regarding show_sql, the sql IS being logged, just no parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the only answer is to have Glassfish use log4j.

[This article describes how](http://blogs.oracle.com/naman/entry/configure_log4j_for_use_in).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at p6spy, a JDBC provider going in between Hibernate and your real JDBC provider and logging sql statements.

I haven't tried it on Glassfish, but check out this tutorial: http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/using_p6spy_and_the_glassfish

Answer (score 0):

Open your spring bean configuration file. That is the place where you would configure hibernate session factory (what generally goes in `hibernate.cfg.xml`)

Look for the `bean` definition of following nature. Note that it is possible to define these in a separate configuration file.

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3....
```

This is the place where you need to set properties `show_sql` and `format_sql` to true.

Also, locate your project's log4j configuration (or in glassfish console) and introduce following settings:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

More details [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44119.html), [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=980936) and [here](http://blog.aplikacja.info/2010/03/how-to-debug-hibernate-sql-queries-with-parameters/)

Comment: I appreciate it. All these links seem to be dealing just with hibernate not with Spring+hibernate+glassfish. There is something odd going on with this particular combination. For example, show_sql is in persistence.xml and searching for "springramework.org.hibernate" returns nothing. Also, the log-levels defined in the glassfish console go "server" through "finest" and don't mesh with the log levels that log4j usually has (there's no DEBUG level for example)

Comment: per my understanding glassfish does not use log4j. You would be more at luck having a log4j set up for your application. You will have to pass the `-Dlog4j.configuration` parameter through jvm settings in glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish admin console -> Configurations -> Server-config -> Logger Settings -> Log levels -> Add Logger -> org.hibernate.type : FINEST

[image: Glassfish logger settings]

source : https://cumacakmak.wordpress.com/2015/01/18/glassfish-hibernate-binding-parameters-easy-way/